# How do I find the image of a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

B is a set where $x_1,x_2$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_1^2 + x_2^2\leq 1\wedge x_1\geq 0.$

A function $f:B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
f(x_1 ,x_2 )=x_1^2 x_2^2 +3x_1 x_2 +x_2 -4.
\end{equation*}

State the image of $f$.

From what I understand, this equation represents a unit circle, where $x_1$ is the $\cos$ function and $x_2$ is the $\sin$ function.

I found the partial derivatives with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ in order to find the critical points.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 2x_1x_2^2 + 3x_2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 2x_1^2x_2 + 3x_1 + 1
\end{equation}
Then I made them equal to zero and solved the equation.
\begin{equation}
2x_1x_2^2 + 3x_2 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_2 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{-3}{2x_1}
\end{equation}
However I couldn't solve the equation:
\begin{equation}
2x_1^2x_2 + 3x_1 + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
And I'm not really sure what to do after that. I also don't know what I should do with the critical points. Do I test for the boundary conditions? Would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: This post seems very much to be a repost in disguise of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4885986) (asked only 1 hour ago and soon closed), but improved and under another new user name. Instead of reposting (which is forbidden), original posts should be edited to improve them, and have them reopened. If my guess was right, please do so and delete this repost.

Comment: @AnneBauval Here is one more: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4885156 Probably it was an exercise.

Comment: @PaulFrost Oh, so my guess that is was a repost must be wrong! Thank you.